# Slide out and fade effect using jQuery and localScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) to create a content slider. The problem is that I want to give a fade effect to the div that I'm sliding out, to make it fade before it disappears. 
Does anyone have any idea how can I make this? I tried something with onBefore and onAfter but I didn't get what I expected.

Thanks!

LE: here is the code that I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
      var localScroll = $('#slider .slideshow-wrapper')
      var localSections = $('#slider .slideshow-wrapper ul.slideshow li');
      var local = $('#slider ul.slideshow');
      local.css('width', localSections[0].offsetWidth * localSections.length);

      var localScrollOptions = {
        target: localScroll,
        items: localSections,
        navigation: 'ul.tabs li a',
        hash: 'false',
        axis: 'xy',
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'swing'
        //onAfter: fadeAway
      };
      $('.container').serialScroll(localScrollOptions);

      $('ul.tabs').find('a span').click(selectNav);


  });
```

Comment: SolutionYogi, I made an edit and posted the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `fadeOut` because it sets the div style to `display:none` and thus the div has a zero height and width making the scrollTo plugin mess up pretty bad. I would suggest using opacity. In the code below I set the minimum opacity to 0.2 because when I set it to zero, it was hard to tell the content was scrolling.

I took the LocalScroll Demo and made these modifications - it seems to work pretty well. I didn't try to match your code because I know the code below works with the demo and your question title says localScroll but your code uses serialScroll. Anyway, I'm guessing the `ul.slideshow li` in your code should be equivalent to the `.sub` in the code below.

```
$.localScroll({
 target: '#content', // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
 queue: false,
 duration: 500,
 hash: false,
 easing: 'swing',
 onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
  // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
  $('.sub').animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 250);
 },
 onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
  // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
  $(anchor).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 250);
 }
});
```

Edit: I posted a demo at this [pastebin](http://pastebin.me/e645538b29a0f3b72a911d1daff91733)

Comment: +1, very nice answer. Not sure if Boris will be back to accept though, it was an old question I cleaned up and Boris hasn't been here for quite some months. 'Tis a good point about fadeOut and widths and messing the scrolling :-)

Comment: LOL thanks... I didn't even pay attention to the date of this post. I'm not sure how I got to it LOL.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/queue

Comment: Thanks Thubkin but I'm not sure that works with the code that I have.